# set ticks with logarithmic scale

Tags: matplotlib, plot, logarithm

It seems that the `set_xticks` is not working in log scale:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 200, 500])
plt.show()
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 200, 500])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

or

```
ax1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().labelOnlyBase = False
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Hi, Could you add some explanation as well as a plot of what this outcome looks like?

Comment: the second option will keep the logarithmic notation in the ticks, ie 20 is going to be 10^1.3

Comment: This is fine if the labels match their numeric value, but what if you want them to be some other strings?

Comment: I am a big fan of http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=funcformatter#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter which lets you wring a function mapping value -> string.  Else use http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=funcformatter#matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter + http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=funcformatter#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator

Comment: @tacaswell: The exponential notation `3x10^1` etc. still remains! How do I remove it ?

Comment: You probably have to turn off the minor formatter as well.

Comment: @tacaswell The 2nd is exactly what I need, but it does not work. I used `set_xticks` to designate what I need, but only the base-conforming ones were displayed, even though the others became 'major' ticks.

Answer (score 24):

I'm going to add a few plots and show how to remove the minor ticks:

The OP:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 300, 500])
plt.show()
```

[image]

To add some specific ticks, as [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) pointed out, you can use  [`matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 300, 500])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[image]

To remove the minor ticks, you can use [`matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.minor.size']`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 0

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 300, 500])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

You could use instead  [`ax1.get_xaxis().set_tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html), it has the same effect (but only modifies the current axis, not all future figures unlike `matplotlib.rcParams`):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 300, 500])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

ax1.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', size=0)
ax1.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', width=0) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The exponential notation `3x10^1` etc. still remains! How do I remove it ?

Comment: @Srivatsan see my answer on how to remove the exponential notation

Answer (score 6):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, NullFormatter
for axis in [ax.xaxis]:
    axis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
    axis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
```

This removes the exponential notation

Answer (score 5):

Would be better to use `np.geomspace` as xticks

```
ax = sns.histplot(arr, log_scale=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_xticks( np.geomspace(1, 1500 ,15).round() )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make a semi-log plot with x-scale logarithmic, there are two options:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

or

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogx(x,y)
```

If you do not need to set the xticks, this two are both fine.

If you **do need** to set the xticks, the second one would be better.

Similarly,

```py
ax.loglog(x,y)
```

is better than

```py
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

when setting ticks is a must;

```py
ax.semilogy(x,y)
```

is better than

```py
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

when setting ticks is needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 200, 500])
plt.xscale("log")       # <<< !
plt.show()
```

[image]