# Python plot log scale set xticks?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot between in Log scale but there are problems ;

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot  as pyplot

Ds = pow(10,5)
D = np.linspace(0, pow(10,6), 6)
alpha=1.44
beta=0.44
A=alpha*pow((D/Ds), beta)
L=1.65
a=exp(-(A*L/4.343))
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xscale('log')
xlim(0.001,1)
ylim(0.1,1)
ax.grid()
line, = ax.plot(D/(Ds),a, color='blue', lw=2, marker='o')
show()
```

but I can not set the value labels of x axis and ticks for it.I want y axis to show between 0 to 1 with 0.1 increments ; x axis to show between 0 to 10 in logscale like 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004  0.005....0.01 0.02  0.03 ... and so on but I can not do it ?

set_xscale automates the ticks and value labels.Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set ticks with logarithmic scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like:

```
import numpy as np
xticks = [0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05,
          0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 10.]
yticks = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks( xticks )
ax.yaxis.set_ticks( yticks )
```

To force labels in all given positions you can you the `set_ticklabels()` method, where you can also control the string format:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels( ['%1.e'  % i for i in xticks] )
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels( ['%1.1f' % i for i in yticks] )
```

Comment: ax.xaxis.set_ticks( [0.001, 0.002 ... ] )
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: yes but it only shows 2 value labels only in x axis, not the others?

Comment: ok... I've updated the answer including set_ticklabels to solve that

Comment: you can check if the ticks are there calling `ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()`, if yes, try adjusting the `xlim(0.001,1)` to a slightly smaller value than 0.001,