# Matplotlib log scale formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

With `matplotlib` when a log scale is specified for an axis, the default method of labeling that axis is with numbers that are 10 to a power eg. 10^6. Is there an easy way to change all of these labels to for example: 1, 5, 10, 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks([1,2,5,10])
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_xlim([1., 10.])
```

[image]