# Matplotlib overlapping tickslabels on log-log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I can't quite figure out how to ask my question properly.
I am trying to set custom x,y ticks on a log-log plot.
Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale?answertab=votes#tab-top) I did,

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xticks([20, 200, 500])
ax1.set_yticks([1, 2,3])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter
    (matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter
    (matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

This results in an overlapping ticklabels on of the axis.
Does anyone knows why is this happening?

[image: output]

Comment: Since I couldn't find the solution, after a lot of searches. I posted it.
Thanks for marking it as duplicate and pointing to the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant github issue :
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8386

Quick Solution:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter
   (matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter
   (matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
```