# Edit tick labels in logarithmic axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm trying to edit the tick labels but I keep getting scientific notation, even after setting the ticks. Here is a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.11, right=0.95, top=0.94)

ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

plt.plot([1,4],[3,6] )

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')

ax.set_xticks([0.7,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,4,5])

ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

which produces this plot

[image]

As you can see `ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')` doesn't seem to work as I keep getting tick labels in scientific notation, and when using `ax.set_xticks` the old tick labels are still present. I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale) topic and it seems like the problem is in the choose of the ticks, if I use for example 0.3 instead of 0.7 as the first tick it works, however I need to do a plot in this specific range and using log scale.

Any work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your code is doing what you need, the problem is the labels from the *minor* ticks that remain unaffected and overlap with the major ticks

you can simply add the line:

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
```

full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.11, right=0.95, top=0.94)

ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

plt.plot([1,4],[3,6] )

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')

ax.set_xticks([0.7,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,4,5])
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
```

[image]

Comment: you are absolutely right, now it works perfect. Thanks.