# For log scale plots in Matplotlib, how do I label ticks by their power, x, instead of the actual value, 10^x?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

When using Matplotlib's `loglog` function to produce plots in log scale, it always labels the ticks as the original value expressed in scientific notation, like so:[image]

However, I'd rather label the ticks by the powers themselves, like so:

[image]

Is there a way to use Matplotlib's log scale functions to do this, besides manually changing each tick label?

I would preferably like to use Matplotlib's log scale (as opposed to plotting log y VS log x directly) because I like the way it handles negative numbers (which sometimes creep unwanted into data).

Comment: Would that be what `LogFormatterExponent` does?

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for. However, the minor ticks are left in a logarithmic scale which looks nothing like the ticks of my plot above.

Comment: So, it would solve my problem if I knew how to space the minor ticks linearly

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530857/565489)?

Comment: Spacing minor ticks linearly on a logarithmic axis would be scientifically unsound, because it suggests to the viewer that they look at a linear scaling.