# Matplotlib xticks overlapping with default ones

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot with a limited number of ticks in x-axis. I followed this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale). And it almost working, however, I have my number scale between 0.1 to 1, and I would still like to do similar operation: only shows`[0.2, 0.3, 0.6]` in scalar format. The plot is restricted to a log-log plot. And I got this:

[image: overlapping]

Obviously, we see the overlapping in `[0.2, 0.3, 0.6]` and no overlapping for `0.4`. How I can remove the original set of the xticks?
My program is attached here:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 8)
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.plot([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.set_xticks([0.2, 0.3, 0.6])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `0.4` is minor ticks:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax1.plot([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.set_xticks([0.2, 0.3, 0.6], minor=False)
ax1.set_xticklabels([],minor=True) # turn minor label off
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can think of major ticks like `10,20,30...` and minor ticks like `12,14,16,18, 22, 24,26,28...`, i.e. finer grain than major ticks, but may not be as important.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was not aware of that before.