# How to make a Heatmap plot with log scale x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have the following heatmap plot using `contourf()`:

```
inclination = np.pi/6

def power(inclination,phi):
    h1=1.7 
    h2=0.5 
    D = np.arange(0.5, 12.0, 0.015)
    r = np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
    freq = 865.7 
    lmb = 300/freq 
    H = D**2/(D**2+2*h1*h2)
    theta = 4*np.pi*h1*h2/(lmb*D)
    q_e = H**2*(np.sin(theta))**2 + (1 - H*np.cos(theta))**2
    sigma = 1.94
    N_1 = np.random.normal(0,sigma,D.shape)
    rnd = 10**(-N_1/10)
    F = 10 
    power=0.8
    R,PHI = np.meshgrid(r,phi[1:-1])
    alpha=inclination + np.arcsin((h1-h2)/R)
    gain=3.136*(np.tan(alpha)*np.sin(np.pi/2*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(PHI)))**2
    y=10*np.log10( 1000*(power*gain*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*np.pi*R)**2) *1.2*1*F)*q_e*rnd )
    return (R,PHI,y)

phi=np.linspace(0, np.pi,num=787)
x,y,z = power(np.pi/4,phi)
import cmocean
cmap = cmocean.cm.oxy
plt.contourf(x, y, z, 20, cmap=cmap)
cb=plt.colorbar();
plt.xlim(None, 12)
plt.ylim(0, np.pi)
plt.xlabel('Distance [m]', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Phi [radians]', fontsize=12)
```

which plots

[image]

I would like to plot this heatmap log scaling the x-axis, but I have not found any example to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this at the end, right before `plt.show()`.

```
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to remove the x labels from 2x10^0 to only 2 and the other distance labels?

Comment: @user1993416 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale

Comment: @bretertainer I cannot make the change of format using the link of your comment. I am going to post another question for this. Thanks.