# Formatting custom labels on a logscale axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplot lib to plot some curves with the x-axis set to a log scale. I figured out how to set custom ticks from [set ticks with logarithmic scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale):

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks([0.001, 0.003, 0.010, 0.033, 0.10, 0.33, 1.0, 3.3, 10.0, 33.0, 100.0])
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', size=0, width=0)
plt.savefig('logscale.png')
plt.close()
```

This code produces the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the two leftmost ticks are `0.00` instead of `0.001` and `0.003` as they should be. How can I format these to show more digits after the decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScalarFormatter` automatically determines a useful number of significant digits to show. This is most often desired. However, `ScalarFormatter` is not optimized to be used on log scales. Hence it will fail in this case.

Because here, we don't need much of the capabilities of `ScalarFormatter` anyways, we may opt for a `StrMethodFormatter` instead. For three digits, use e.g.

```
matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:1.3f}")
```