# Logarithmic x-axis with custom xticks with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Using the plot functionality in pandas dataframe I try to get a proper logarithmic x-axis: sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Freq':[63,125,250,500],'A':[1,2,3,4]})

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(df['Freq'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Freq'])
df.set_index('Freq').plot(ax=ax)
```

This does however just result in 2 sets of x-ticks.. on top of each other:

[image: logxplot]

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale), changed the order of commands, but that does not change anything.
Anyone any ideas....?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried the following

```
import pandas as pd 

fig,ax = plt.subplots() df =
pd.DataFrame({'Freq':[63,125,250,500],'A':[1,2,3,4]})
df.plot(ax=ax,x='Freq',logx=True,xticks=df['Freq'])
```

with almost identical results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `logx` in the Pandas plotting interface directly.

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Freq':[63,125,250,500],'A':[1,2,3,4]})

df.set_index('Freq').plot(ax=ax, logx=True)```
````

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that and that doesn't change the result unfortunately.